# issue with boost json parser

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, jsonparser

I am trying to use boost `json_parser`. I have included `boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp` in my `cpp` file.

I have not included any other code. But I am getting many compilation  errors  like error:

> ```
> boost::spirit::classic' has not been declared and
>     In function void boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json_internal(std::basic_istream<typename
> Ptree::key_type::value_type, std::char_traits<typename
> Ptree::key_type::value_type> >&, Ptree&, const std::string&):
>      [exec] /usr/include/boost/property_tree/detail/json_parser_read.hpp:288:
> error: 'classic' is not a namespace-name
> ```

Can you help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you included  <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp> first?

Comment: Property Tree has its own hand written json parser for a long time already (since Boost 1.59)

Comment: As @NikitaKniazev is saying. property_tree is not by it self a json parser written in spirit. property_tree is a data structure that can be populated by using its own json_parser. So I wonder what the source code you compile is from?